# Get row and column size in pixels from grid manager of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have my rows and columns of a Tkinter GUI changing size when I resize my main window but I need to manually resize a matplotlib figure to fit the new grid size.

I am using the grid geometry manager.

How can I get the size of the row/column in pixels that the Figure is in so I can resize the figure?

Comment: ```sticky="nsew"```?

Comment: This does not resize a matplotlib figure. I just want to get the size of a row and column.

Comment: The answer is in the standard documentation. Search for `grid_bbox`.

Comment: Thank you. I searched for similar questions but I was not about to find anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am Inexperienced with Stack Overflow.  Do I delete this question, leave it unanswered or answer it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The answer is in the standard documentation. Search for grid_bbox" – Bryan Oakley